# Porque é que esta pergunta esta a ser fechada?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, razões-fechamento

Porque é que esta pergunta [Servidor MySQL não consegue iniciar no CentOS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30840/erro-mysql-centos-starting-mysqlcouldnt-find-mysql-server) está a ser votada para ser fechada? Não encontro motivo nenhum pela qual possa ser fechada. É alguém com um problema, que já tentou de tudo e não sabe como resolver.

Comment: Embora não tenham pedido mais informações sobre o problema, eu votei considerando superficial e pouco clara. Os comentários - mesmo com boa intenção - acabam sendo uma adivinhação de possíveis causas( "pode ser isso, pode ser aquilo"... ). EMHO

Comment: @PapaCharlie como se pode ver pelos comentários nem o AP sabe a causa do problema.

Comment: Verdade, mas fica dificil ajudar sem o minimo de informacao - apenas tentei seguir o padrao para questoes formuladas. Nao me importo de retirar o voto, farei agora sem problema. Estou no mobile, desculpem a grafia.

Comment: Vi agora que fecharam. Se optarem pela reabertura eu voto.